# How can I fix a Broken Pipe error?

Tags: bash, ruby, .bash-profile, rvm

I recently reinstalled RVM (following the instructions at http://rvm.io) after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 when I got an SSD Drive.

Now, when I type: `type rvm | head -1`

I receive the following error:

```
rvm is a function
-bash: type: write error: Broken pipe
```

But if I immediately repeat the command then I only receive:

```
rvm is a function
```

And it appears everything is ok? What's happening? What can I do to fix it? It doesn't happen always. It appears to be more sporadic. I've tried to find some kind of pattern to it but haven't yet.

Comment: Why don't you just use `type -t rvm` so no need for piping?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Seeing "Broken pipe" in this situation is rare, but normal.

When you run `type rvm | head -1`, bash executes `type rvm` in one process, `head -1` in another.<sup>1</sup> The stdout of `type` is connected to the "write" end of a *pipe*, the stdin of `head` to the "read" end. Both processes run at the same time.

The `head -1` process reads data from stdin (usually in chunks of 8 kB), prints out a single line (according to the `-1` option), and exits, causing the "read" end of the pipe to be closed. Since the `rvm` function is quite long (around 11 kB after being parsed and reconstructed by bash), this means that `head` exits while `type` still has a few kB of data to write out.

At this point, since `type` is trying to write to a pipe whose other end has been closed – a *broken* pipe – the write() function it caled will return an EPIPE error, translated as "Broken pipe". In addition to this error, the kernel also sends the SIGPIPE signal to `type`, which by default kills the process immediately.

(The signal is very useful in interactive shells, since most users do not want the first process to keep running and trying to write to nowhere. Meanwhile, non-interactive services ignore SIGPIPE – it would not be good for a long-running daemon to die on such a simple error – so they find the error code very useful.)

However, signal delivery is not 100% immediate, and there may be cases where write() returns EPIPE and the process continues to run for a short while before receiving the signal. In this case, `type` gets enough time to notice the failed write, translate the error code and even print an error message to stderr before being killed by SIGPIPE. (The error message says "-bash: type:" since `type` is a built-in command of bash itself.)

This seems to be more common on multi-CPU systems, since the `type` process and the kernel's signal delivery code can run on different cores, literally at the same time.

It would be possible to remove this message by patching the `type` builtin (in bash's source code) to immediately exit when it receives an EPIPE from the write() function.

However, it's nothing to be concerned about, and it is not related to your `rvm` installation in any way.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried about it. I did about an hours worth of googling last night troubleshooting my rvm install and doing repairs to it trying to fix it. I'd just swapped out with an SSD drive and use LVM and encrypted the hard drive so there was a lot of variables coming into play and I just wasn't sure what might have went sideways. Thank you for putting my mind at ease!

Comment: I have been piping the output of `ls` through `head -1` for years, and today I'm getting a broken pipe message.

Comment: (Note: The "Broken pipe" error doesn't come from the signal. It comes from the _errno_. While the shell may otherwise show text messages for signal-induced-exits, it's usually smart enough to pretend that a SIGPIPE exit was a 'clean' one.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity what _errno_?

Answer (score 40):

You can fix a broken pipe **at the expense of another process** by inserting `tail -n +1` in your pipe, like this:

> type rvm | tail -n +1 | head -1

The `+1` tells `tail` to print the first line of input and everything that follows. Output will be exactly the same as if `tail -n +1` wasn't there, but the program is smart enough to check standard output and closes the pipe down cleanly. No more *broken pipes*.

Comment: Nice trick. I've used in a different situation than the one provided here. Thanks!

Comment: Note: you may need to use use `tail -n +1`, otherwise tail thinks the "+1" is meant to be a filename.

Comment: Looked like a great solution, but on Ubuntu 14.04.2 with tail 8.21 I get "tail: write error: Broken pipe", which is no improvement.

Comment: Version 8.21 seems to require the -n flag. see edit

Comment: @RogerDueck is correct.  I also see this on a Mandriva system for a similar sort of problem `find /var/lib/mysql -xdev -type f -daystart -mmin +5 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ldt | tail -n +1 | head` reliably yields `xargs: ls: terminated by signal 13`.  As we know, the problem is one of input exhaustion and there's really only one command that deals with buffering: dd.  Adding `| dd obs=1M` to the pipeline fixes the SIGPIPE for my use case.

Comment: It the output of the first command is binary, you can use `tail -c +1`, I was sometimes getting the broken pipe error when piping the binary output of ImageMagick `convert` (PDF to TIFF conversion) to `tesseract` (an OCR app supporting only TIFF files)

Comment: I will further amend my suggestion, although I will note that I don't believe that xargs or type should be kvetching about SIGPIPE, to this: `type rvm | (head -1 ; dd of=/dev/null)`  This, of course, is similar to other suggestions as it's causing all of the input to be processed, but `dd` should be the most efficient program to handle such things.

Comment: Commentary on SIGPIPE violators here: https://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-userlevel/2013/01/07/msg007110.html

Comment: @AndrewBeals *(...) there's really only one command that deals with buffering: dd* Reference needed.

Comment: @AndrewBeals It does not help, if the source part of pipe is slow.

Comment: Then this will break the `tail` process in turn as the `head` command finished too early.

Answer (score 9):

Let's try with `yes`, an endless process printing yes...

Before, the `yes` process was killed by SIGPIPE when reached limit.

```sh
➜ set -o pipefail
➜ yes | head -n 1
y
➜ echo $?        
141
```

My solution

```sh
➜ yes | (head -n 1;dd status=none of=/dev/null)
y


# the process will still running and output to null
```

You can replace `yes` with your program.

Comment: `cat > /dev/null` works, too. Indeed, like @user1686 said, the timing between erroring out with `EPIPE` vs the asynchronous `SIGPIPE` affects the error code.  In my WSL2 system, echoing 162 or more empty lines exhibited the transition from 0 (ignored EPIPE?) to 141 (SIGPIPE, bash exit code 128+13) as the exit code. Then `cat` appears to consume the rest of the pipe (just as dd).  `$ { for((i=0;i<200;i++)); do echo; done } | { head -n 1; cat > /dev/null; }; echo $?

0`

Answer (score 3):

The `write error: Broken pipe` message refers to a writing process that tries to write to a pipe with no readers left on the reading end of that pipe and the special circumstance that the `SIGPIPE` signal is set to be ignored either by the current or the parent process. If it was the parent process that set `SIGPIPE` to be ignored, it is not possible for the child process to undo that again in a non-interacitive shell.

However, it is possible to kill `type rvm` when `head -1` terminates by using explicit subshells. This way we can background `type rvm`, send `typepid` to the `head -1` subshell and then implement a trap on `EXIT` there to kill `type rvm` explicitly.

```
trap "" PIPE        # parent process sets SIGPIPE to be ignored
bash                # start child process
export LANG=C
# create a fake rvm function
eval "
rvm() {
$(printf 'echo line of rvm code %s\n' {1..10000})
}
"

# rvm is a function
# bash: type: write error: Broken pipe
type rvm | head -1

# kill type rvm when head -1 terminates
# sleep 0: do nothing but with external command
( (sleep 0; type rvm) & echo ${!} ; wait ${!} ) | 
    (trap 'trap - EXIT; kill "$typepid"; exit' EXIT; typepid="$(head -1)"; head -1)
```

Comment: From grawity's answer: *`type` gets enough time to notice the failed write, translate the error code and even print an error message to stderr before being killed by SIGPIPE*. I think your solution doesn't prevent the *producer* process (`type` here) from reacting to the failed write (due to closed pipe), does it?

Comment: IIRC there may be some race condition in this code at least if you use greater n for `head -n`. Maybe it is better to read typeid by `read -r typeid` than by `typepid="$(head -1)"`.

Comment: To be more general you should run the kill command like `kill "$typepid" 2>/dev/null || :` to avoid error, if the leaf side of the pipe finishes first.

Comment: See my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588332/111181) to a related question.

Comment: This gave me the clue to fix this: for me `if aws configure list-profiles | grep -q blabla; then` was showing broken pipe, whereas this works: `if echo $( aws configure list-profiles ) | grep -q blabla; then`.

Comment: Yes, I tested that your code may sometimes give the 2nd row of _type_'s output.

Comment: But why would the caller set PIPE to `''`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `awk` to replace `head`, and not eagerly quits prematurely. (this should work on all variance of awk implementations):

```
type rvm | awk 'NR==1'
```

Or more generically, for the first N lines:

```
# First 10 lines:
type rvm | awk -v N=10 'NR<=N'
```

To explain the awk script: `NR==1` is the condition, when met, the action should be taken. `NR` is the awk variable for the current Number of Records. The action usually is given after the condition enclosed in `{...}`. When the action is omitted, it is default to print the entire line `{print}`. So `awk 'NR==1'` means to print those lines whose "Number of Records" is 1, which is the first line.

Similarly, in `awk -v N=10 'NR<=N'`, `-v N=10` means passing `N=10` as a variable to the following awk script. And `'NR<=N'` means to print those lines whose "Number of Records" is less/eq `N`.

Why this doesn't trigger broken pipe error? It's because in above awk script, it processes every line until the end of file, so it won't close the reading end of the pipe prematurely.

Some performance considerations:

1. we don't cache the lines and print them out in an `END` section, so memory-wise it's OK to handle large number of lines
2. since we don't reference fields here (e.g., `$1`, `$2`, ...), field splitting should not happen, which further saves computation splitting potentially long lines and large amount of lines.

   - (Per POSIX doc[1]: "Before the first reference to a field in the record is evaluated, the record shall be split into fields, according to the rules in Regular Expressions, using the value of FS that was current at the time the record was read")

And finally, curiously, if we do want to emulate `head`'s behavior of early exiting (and therefore the broken pipe sympton), we would add `exit` statement:

```
yes | awk -v N=10 'NR<=N; NR>N {exit}'  # print 10 "yes"
```

[1]: [POSIX awk manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the posted answers give complicated ways to replace `head -1`. However, there is a much easier way: `sed -n 1p`.

The above command suppresses echo each line (`-n`) and prints the first line (`1p`). However, it does not stop processing the input after reading the first line.