# Is there a way around broken pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, pipe

I have a directory with a large number of files.

```
./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/
```

Within a script I'd like to find all subdirs in it, to sort them and to output to a bash array. So, I do:

```
SubdirsArray=(`find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort`)
```

Executing the script, I get the following error messages:

```
    sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
    sort: write error
```

As explained in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error): probably `sort` executes and closes the pipe, before `find` completes writing to it. Thus write() command initiated by `find` gets an error EPIPE "Broken pipe", OS sends `find` a SIGPIPE. Before the SIGPIPE reaches `find`, it prints the error message, then gets SIGPIPE and dies.

**Questions:**

1. So, what does my `SubdirsArray` contain? The Subdirs, that `find` found, but `sort` left unsorted?
2. If so, than what would be the way around this issue with broken pipes? Make find write it's results to a temporary file and then make sort read it?

   I don't understand, why "it's also nothing to be concerned about" if it happens within a non-interactive shell: why? My `SubdirsArray` contains something unsorted and further in the script, I assume, that its elements are sorted?!
3. I get two error messages:

   ```
   sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
   sort: write error
   ```

In this [thread](http://linuxwhy.com/showthread.php?55735-Sort-Write-Error-occured-while-merging) it is suggested, that `sort` doesn't have enough space in a temporary directory to sort all the input. But, doesn't it mean, that sort got something from find?!? I'm confused...
Anyways, I tried to use

```
SubdirsArray=(`find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort -T /home/temp_dir`)
```

but it didn't help.

P.S.

I'm not sure whether it's important, but I use `find|sort` in a multi-processor script: several processors execute the same command at once in the subshells.

Comment: `sort` can't do anything before it read the input in full and besides if it was the `sort` ending prematurely, it would be `find` reporting broken pipe, not `sort`. The error in the other thread you mention looks very different and is indeed different.

Comment: @JanHudec thank you for pointing that out, I didn't pay attention, to what command reported the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
> ```

The problem is not between `find` and `sort`. The `sort` has problem with *output*, which means **the shell is not willing to read as long list in a variable.**

You'll have to process the input with `while read`…, storing it in temporary file if you need it more than once. With the added advantage, that this splits on newline only, so it correctly handles filenames with spaces which the backtick approach does not.

Unfortunately you don't say how you want to use the result, I can't tell you how to exactly rewrite it.

Note, that arrays are not part of POSIX shell specification and there are shells that are noticeably faster than bash, but don't have them. That's why many people, including me, often avoid using them in scripts.

Comment: Jan, thank you for the answer and the comment. I'd like to use `SubdirsArray` in a for loop. So, I will implement your solution like: `find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort > temp.txt; while read Subdir; do myFunction $Subdir; done; rm temp.txt` In the end, I'd like to apply `myFunction` to all `Subdirs`. To do it faster, I try to parallelise my code and use `N` subshells with `wait`. Each subshell should take only it's part of Subdirs. I didn't want to send a long array of Subdirs it should handle to each subshell, but first/last index of `SubdirsArray`.

Comment: @user1541776: Don't forget to redirect input into the loop. It could be done even without temporary file, but probably not if you want to split it first.

Comment: you mean `find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort > temp.txt; while read Subdir; do myFunction $Subdir; done ` < "temp.txt" `; rm temp.txt` ?

Comment: @user1541776: Yes, exactly. `read` just reads from standard input.

Comment: @user1541776: You can also pipe to the loop, but it will than run in a subshell, on in shell that has it (like bash, but not ash/dash) you can use process substitution, i.e. like `<(find ... | sort)`.

Comment: thank you. So, the final version would be 1. piping to the loop: `find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort | while read Subdir; do myFunction $Subdir; done` or alternatively 2. using process substitution `while read Subdir; do myFunction $Subdir; done <(find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort)`

Comment: @user1541776: Yes.

Comment: Thanks, Jan! Bugfix: while read Subdir; do myFunction $Subdir; done **<** <(find ./I_am_a_dir_with_many_subdirs/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort)