# Oldest file in directory tree matching pattern

Tags: linux, busybox

I'm looking for a good portable way of finding the oldest file in a directory tree matching a pattern, explicitly without using `find`'s `-printf` option.
So far I found this solution: https://superuser.com/a/552609/1182477 which I extend with a pattern like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr | head -n 1
```

But this fails silently when no file matches the pattern. I get the oldest file regardless of the pattern.
My diagnosis so far: when nothing matches the pattern, nothing gets passend into `xargs` and thus `ls -ltr` lists all files.
How can I solve this? I want to get nothing out, when nothing matches the pattern.

And maybe, as a bonus, a solution that also avoids the ARG_MAX problem with long file lists?
(And before someone asks: logrotate is not available on the system.)

One thing that I stumpled upon in my diagnostics and what could help me find a solution to the above:

```
ls *.csv
```

lists files matching that pattern. But

```
*.csv | xargs ls
```

lists all files. Shouldn't both of them do the same?

Thank You very much.

Comment: Define "portable". POSIX? Also runs in Windows?

Comment: The command `xargs` has an option `-r` which prevents the command from running if there list of arguments is empty.

Comment: @xenoid: look at the tags, so no windows. I'm not so sure which platforms I should aim at. All I know, I'm running busybox, and there's no -printf option in find.

Comment: @Kapil: Thank You for leaving the reputation of a good answer to me. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With busybox, your question can be answered by simply doing:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec stat -c '%y %n'  {} + | sort | head -1
```

(removing the time stamp from the final result is left as an exercise for the reader)

This also avoids the SIGPIPE error you can get with your `xargs`-based version if there are very many files (unless you use [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error/642932#642932))

Comment: I have no `stat` on this BusyBox v1.30.1. (It's a router running it.) Answer works on my Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks for pointing to the `tail -n +1` trick. But it doesn't relieve the signal 13 problem on neither systems.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the comment of Kapil I found this working:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0r ls -ltr | head -n 1
```